# IF And Or Statement not working correctly - Apps Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am trying to have the below 3 stage checks run on my googlesheet. I need it to match all 3 conditions before moving to the function call action.

1. Confirm the SheetName is one of 3 options
2. Confirm that the column edited is the required column
3. Confirm that the text entered into the column matches the required text.

So far points 2 and 3 seem to work without issue. My issue is that for 1 it doesn't seem to pick up. When editing SheetName 'Stage 5' I am getting the function call for Stage 3.

```
function confirmUpdatedSheet(e){
  //Confirm field edited is Stage X Approval Status and confirm status matches action
    //required in function. If not then exit the function.

      if (((SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName() !== "Stage 3") || (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName() !== "STAGE 3 update v1") || ((SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName() !== "STAGE 3 update v2")))
       && (e.range.columnStart === 20)
       && ((e.range.offset(0, 0).getDisplayValue() === "Approved") || (e.range.offset(0, 0).getDisplayValue() === "Approved with conditions"))) {
      updateSt3Approval();
       return;
      } else if (((SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName() !== "Stage 4") || (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName() !== "STAGE 4 update v1") || ((SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName() !== "STAGE 4 update v2")))
       && (e.range.columnStart === 19)
       && ((e.range.offset(0, 0).getDisplayValue() === "Approved") || (e.range.offset(0, 0).getDisplayValue() === "Approved with conditions"))) {
      updateSt4Approval();
       return;
    } else if (((SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName() !== "Stage 5") || (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName() !== "STAGE 5 update v1") || ((SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName() !== "STAGE 5 update v2")))
       && (e.range.columnStart === 20)
       && ((e.range.offset(0, 0).getDisplayValue() === "Approved") || (e.range.offset(0, 0).getDisplayValue() === "Approved with conditions"))) {
      updateSt5Approval();
       return;
    } else {
      return;
    }
}
```

Comment: `e.range.offset(0, 0).getDisplayValue()` is the same as `e.range.getDisplayValue()`

Comment: Did you mean `=== "Stage 3"` and not `!== "Stage 3"`?

Comment: I had tried both, but neither were successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function confirmUpdatedSheet(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const na = sh.getName();
  const sobj = { case1: { sheets: ["Stage 3", "STAGE 3 update v1", "STAGE 3 update v2"], col: 20, value: ["Approved", "Approved with conditions"] }, case2: { sheets: ["Stage 4", "STAGE 4 update v1", "STAGE 4 update v2"], col: 19, value: ["Approved", "Approved with conditions"] }, case3: { sheets: ["Stage 5", "STAGE 5 update v1", "STAGE 5 update v2"], col: 20, value: ["Approved", "Approved with conditions"] } }
  const idx1 = sobj.case1.sheets.indexOf(na);
  const idx2 = sobj.case1.value.indexOf(e.value)
  if (~idx1 && e.range.columnStart == sobj.case1.col && ~idx2) {
    updateSt3Approval();
    return;
  }
  const idx3 = sobj.case2.sheets.indexOf(na);
  const idx4 = sobj.case2.value.indexOf(e.value)
  if (~idx3 && e.range.columnStart == sobj.case2.col && ~idx4) {
    updateSt4Approval();
    return;
  }
  const idx5 = sobj.case3.sheets.indexOf(na);
  const idx6 = sobj.case3.value.indexOf(na);
  if (~idx5 && e.range.columnStart == sobj.case3.col && ~idx6) {
    updateSt5Approval();
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this. Just wondering, in the if statement you have ~idx and !idx, I've not really used indexof before so was just wondering what the difference was in the ~ and !

Comment: Ah, thank you! I am getting the below error when I run:

ReferenceError: case1 is not defined
    at confirmUpdatedSheet(Code:22:39)

Comment: yes i fixed that

Comment: Thanks, I must be copying across wrong. Will try and work out. Thanks for your help.